# On-chain performance of HashSet

Tags: hashing, compute-budget, compute

How many Compute Units (CU) does it cost to init a HashSet on-chain and perform a contains() check? Intuitively, the limited bpf instruction set will have a high overhead for hashing.

Consider these options, which will perform better for 10 items, 100 items, 1000 items, or 10k items on-chain (we probably wouldn't have more than that due to memory size)

With Hash:

```
    pub fn with_hash(
        &mut self,
        ids: &HashSet<u16>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        self.series.iter_mut().for_each(|x| {
            if ids.contains(&x.some_id) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        });
        Ok(())
    }
```

Or using a Vec:

```
    pub fn with_vec(
        &mut self,
        ids: &mut Vec<u16>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        ids.sort_unstable();

        self.series.iter_mut().for_each(|x| {
            if ids.binary_search(&x.some_id).is_ok() {
                // Do something
            }
        });
        Ok(())
    }
```

My Guess:

10, 100 items = Vec will win regardless at this size.

1000, 10k+ items = not sure, depends on the CU overhead of .contains()

Comment: This would be a really cool study to do! I'd be very curious to see the results. And don't sleep on `BTreeSet`, it could also be quite good